# Macfusion not working

Tags: macos, sftp

I would like to mount an SFTP drive on OS X. I tried MacFUSION but it doesn't seem to work, always gives "Could not mount filesystem: Mount process has terminated unexpectedly". According to [Can MacFusion be used under Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90774/can-macfusion-be-used-under-mountain-lion), MacFUSION no longer works. Are there any alternatives or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for recommendations for anything FTP and SFTP, I would recommend either Fetch, or Transmit.  I don't know if there's a workaround to getting MacFUSION to work on Mavericks, sorry.